# unable to scroll the left pane of google maps using puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

I am trying to scroll down on the left Pane of the google maps of this page

https://www.google.com/maps/search/super+markets+in+Dubai/@25.2603029,55.2198231,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!2m1!6e6

but i am nt able to do soo i tried multiple methods

one of the method did work but it barely scrolled 100px or soo
i want to load all the elements on left pane as it contains lazy loading of the data

the barely working method

```
  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const scrollableSection = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"
    );
    console.log(scrollableSection.length);
    console.log(scrollableSection[0]);

    scrollableSection[1].scrollTop = scrollableSection[1].scrollHeight;
  });
```

my code

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const scraper = async (url) => {
  function wait(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), ms));
  }

  async function autoScroll(page) {
    await page.evaluate(async () => {
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        var totalHeight = 0;
        var distance = 100;
        const scrollableSection = document.getElementsByClassName(
          "section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"
        );
        console.log(scrollableSection);
        var timer = setInterval(() => {
          var scrollHeight = scrollableSection[1].scrollHeight;
          console.log(scrollHeight);
          window.scrollTo(0, distance);
          totalHeight += distance;
          if (totalHeight >= scrollHeight) {
            console.log("solved");
            clearInterval(timer);
            resolve();
          }
          console.log("rejcetc");
        }, 100);
      });
    });
  }

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: ["--no-sandbox", "--disable-setuid-sandbox"],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.setUserAgent(
    "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
  );

  await page.setViewport({ width: 1200, height: 768 });

  await page.goto(url, {
    waitUntil: "networkidle0",
  });

  // await autoScroll(page);

  await page.evaluate(() => {
    const scrollableSection = document.getElementsByClassName(
      "section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"
    );
    console.log(scrollableSection.length);
    console.log(scrollableSection[0]);

    scrollableSection[1].scrollTop = scrollableSection[1].scrollHeight;
  });
  //  await browser.close();
};

scraper(
  "https://www.google.com/maps/search/super+markets+in+Dubai/@25.2603029,55.2198231,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!2m1!6e6"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Братишка, if this still actual for you,
you can try somthing like this:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
        const scrollableSection = document.getElementsByClassName(
          "section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"
        );
        scrollableSection[1].scrollTop = scrollableSection[1].scrollHeight;
      });
    
    await page.waitFor(Math.random()  *1000)
    
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const scrollableSection = document.getElementsByClassName(
          "section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"
        );

        scrollableSection[1].scrollTop = scrollableSection[1].scrollHeight;
      });
    
    await page.waitFor(Math.random() * 1000)
    
    await page.evaluate(() => {
        const scrollableSection = document.getElementsByClassName(
          "section-layout section-scrollbox scrollable-y scrollable-show section-layout-flex-vertical"
        );

        scrollableSection[1].scrollTop = scrollableSection[1].scrollHeight;
      });
    await page.waitFor(Math.random() * 1000)
```